# how to manage encoded json from http get using Bot framework Composer

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have 2 different send http get requests from a dialog in Azure Bot composer. The first as a git hub request after getting a token returns successfully which is a single json object. The second returns gobbeldy goo and that result is an array of json objects.

The first [image]

And the second which by the way is served from Az Api manager.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling the API separately, from Postman for example? If Postman shows the same result, then I'd say that is an expected result.

Comment: The api call from postman works ok but what is interesting is that postman defines the response as gziped which I'm assuming is done out of Api manager. I'm thinking that there must be a setting out in Api Manager to compress or not. Content-Encoding = gzip Postman just takes care of it.